# Java 8 java.time not mapped to mysql properly

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, java-8

When I try to save java.util.time -> LocalDate or Instant in MySQL through spring data, it captures it but not in human-readable format instead of in some alien language. And the data type in MySQL becomes tinyblob.

Now the problem is, I am not able to do any date related query directly. Like I want to fetch all the data not older than 10 minutes to run the below query but got no result. Although there is data.

```
select * from time_slot_history where updated_date > date_sub(now(),interval 10 minute);
```

Comment: You're probably using a quite old version of Hibernate then. Don't.

Comment: No, i am using latest version of Hibernate. And also i tried to use Jsr310JpaConverters but got a lot of exceptions

Comment: Try converting `java.util.time` to `java.sql.time`.

Comment: can you post the code of the entity please?

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring boot 2.1.5 or 2.1.6, the LocalDateTime can direct save to mysql. But when I using springboot 1.5.x, I remember I have to manually add jackson-datatype-jdk8, jackson-datatype-jsr310, org.hibernate:hibernate-java8 to make mysql and jaskson support LocalDateTime.

Maybe you can try add "org.hibernate:hibernate-java8"